# Add more than one measure in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I like to know how to add more than one measure to a existing measure group in SSAS. I know how to add one column at a time, but my requirement is to add more than one at a time. If any one knows, please reply. Thank you.

Comment: I think you only can ad more than one column at a time when you create a new measure group. Not after it is created already.

Comment: After research, i found out that we can add more than one column at a time, go to cube structure tab under cube design, select the columns needed from  the respective table from adjacent "Data Source View"  area, drag and drop into "Measures" area.